# How do I create a NSToggleButton in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, button, interface-builder

I want to make an NSToggleButton because it suits my needs perfectly: show one image when toggled on, another when it's toggled off.

From Apple's Developer website:

"After the first click, the button displays its alternate image or title; a second click returns the button to its normal state.
This option is called “Toggle” in Interface Builder’s Button Inspector.
Available in OS X v10.0 and later."
- [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSToggleButton)

When looking at the Round Rect Button I created in Interface Builder, however, I can't find a "Toggle" attribute.  My google and StackOverflow searches yield only questions around attributes for the control, but I haven't found a tutorial for creating this button in particular.

How do I create a NSToggleButton in Interface Builder?  Where is it in the Object library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source you provdided is for OSX programming. Not iOS however this can be implemented yourself. A UIButton is just a UIView so add a UIImageView as a subview then when the button is clicked set `hidden` to either YES or NO

Comment: Not sure about implementing this in IB, it may be possible but I don't use IB that much. I can show you how to do it programmatically if you'd like.

Comment: I can dig that. Thanks for adding in a possible equivalent implementation for iOS!

Answer (score 1):

NSToggleButton is an AppKit class -- MacOS X only. You won't find it if you're building an iOS app. Classes from the Foundation framework have an `NS` prefix and are available in iOS (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.), but the user interface classes in iOS are in UIKit and have a `UI` prefix. Take a look at  [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for similar functionality.

Comment: This explains why my search was fruitless.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I see you've edited your response, so I wanted to follow up on the changes as well: a UISwitch sounds exactly like what I was looking for in terms of functionality, but it does not offer an alteration of images to represent the on-off states, unfortunately.  Thanks for bringing it up, though!